# Find number of second child in html element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#">A</a>
        <a href="#">B</a>
    </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#">C</a>
        <a href="#">D</a>
        <a href="#">E</a>
    </span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Do I have straight way to find how many `anchor tags`  are there in Div `mydiv` in `JQuery`
Thanks.

Comment: `var count = $('#mydiv a').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length`:

```
var anchorLength =  $('#mydiv a').length;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NaCHz/)**

---

If you only want to get the total number of anchors inside second `span` inside `#myDiv`, then you can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** or **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector:

```
var anchorLength =  $('#mydiv span:eq(1) a').length;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NaCHz/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to get the anchor those are descendants of div. Once you get them you can use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to get the count.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Wuq/)**

```
$('#mydiv a').length
```

**Description:** Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#mydiv a').length // This return length of a 's in mydiv 
$('#mydiv span:eq(1) a').length // This return second span a 's length
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVSPR/58/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#top > :nth-child(2)').whatever();
```

or

```
$('#top').children(':first-child').next().whatever();
```

get the 2nd child of an unordered list:

```
  $('ul:first-child').next()
```

using jQuery